# Wpf - Display an image without using XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm trying to get an image to display using Wpf. I can't hard-code the image in the XAML file, I have to implement it in the .cs files only. (The images are dynamically displayed)

Here's what I got so far :

```
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:/Users/Pierrick/Desktop/tileset/1.png"));
System.Windows.Controls.Image image1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
image1.Source = imageSource;
```

The code runs fine, but nothing displays. No surprise, I didn't specify the image location in the window, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the Image control to some layout panel in your application. Suppose you have a MainWindow XAML like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can add the Image to the Children collection of the Grid by

```
rootGrid.Children.Add(image1);
```

---

If you are going to dynamically place multiple images at specific locations, you will typically use an ItemsControl with an appropriate view model, that uses a Canvas as its ItemsPanel, and sets each image item's location by binding the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties in its ItemContainerStyle. It would use the Image control in its ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="{Binding Width}"
                    Height="{Binding Height}"
                    Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model would look like this:

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageItem> ImageItems { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the `ItemsSource` property of the ItemsControl is bound to the `ImageItems` property of the view model. The item bindings go to the properties of the data item class `ImageItem`, i.e. the element type of the collection.

You would now create an instance of the view model e.g. in your MainWindow's constructor and assign it to its `DataContext`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel
    {
        ImageItems = new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>()
    };

    vm.ImageItems.Add(new ImageItem
        {
            X = 100,
            Y = 100,
            Width = 100,
            Height = 100,
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...))
        });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: Well, your first example worked to some extend. Only I need to display the image at specific x/y coordinates, so grid aren't perfect in this case. (I should have specified)

Regarding the second example, I will need to display at least a few dozens of images, thats why I need to do it programmatically.

Thanks for the help, I'm closer to the answer now !

Comment: If you are going to put multiple images at specific locations, you would typically use an ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel and an appropriate view model. I'll prepare an example.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll also dig it up on my side

Comment: Just read the edit, great explanation ! I really wish I could accept both of your answers =/

Comment: Accept the one that better answers your question. However, the common approach to display multiple similar items in WPF is to use an ItemsControl or a derived control like ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the layout  your container has, for example if you want to add the image to a Grid, let's say that your window looks like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

to add an image to the `Grid1` programmatically here how :

```
            ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yep.png",UriKind.Relative));
        System.Windows.Controls.Image image1 = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        image1.Source = imageSource;
        Grid.SetColumn(image1, 0);//image1 is added to column 0
        Grid.SetRow(image1, 0);//row 0

        Grid1.Children.Add(image1);
```

Comment: Like Clemens, your example worked to some extend. Only I need to display the image at specific x/y coordinates, so grid aren't perfect in this case. (I should have specified) Still, thanks for the help, I'm closer to the answer now !

Comment: In that case use a Canvas instead and set the left and bottom coordinate of the image using Canvas.SetLeft(images, val); ..

Comment: Cavas.Children.Add(Images1)
Canvas.SetLeft(Image1, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(Image1, 50);